# discord.js Warn bot, members undefined

Tags: discord, bots, undefined, member

So im making a bot for discord, its a warn bot, my whole code is wright, but there is an error that i dont understand
this my code:

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Sorry jij kan dit niet doen");

    if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Je moet een gebruiker meegeven");
    
    if (!args[1]) return message.reply("Je moet een redenene meegeven");

    var warnUser = message.guilt.members.cache.get(message.mentions.users.first().id || message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id)

    var reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    if (!warnuser) return message.reply("Kan de gebruiker niet vinden");

    if(warnUser.permission.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Sorry je kan deze persoon geen waarschuwing geven");

    const warn = JSON.parse(fs,readFileSync("./warns.json", "UTF8"));

    if(!warns[warnUser.id]) warns [warnUser.id] = {
        warns: 0
    }
```

this my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\DISCORDBOT\commands\warn.js:12:34)
```

if i click on it id goes to this line:

```
var warnUser = message.guilt.members.cache.get(message.mentions.users.first().id || message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your try to get user with mention /ID**

```js
var warnUser = message.guilt.members.cache.get(message.mentions.users.first().id || message.guild.members.get(args[0]).id)
```

**For this you can use**

```js
var warnUser = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

`if you need any help with it or any problem leave it in comments`

Comment: okey that dit work but another error coms up its about;args[1].slice is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\DISCORDBOT\commands\warn.js:14:26)

Comment: ```args.slice(1).join(' ') || "No reason specified"```

Comment: then it says args.slice is not a function

Comment: Did you put `;` after it?

Comment: yes i did and stil that error